# When do we return values in PHP functions?

Tags: php, oop

Sorry for the question but I don't understand how this works:

```
class Person {
    public static $age = 1;

    public function haveBirthday() {
        static::$age +=1;
    }
}

$joe = new Person;
$joe->haveBirthday();

echo Person::$age;
```

What I'm not understanding is this:

```
public function haveBirthday() {
    static::$age +=1;
}
```

Isn't supposed to **return** $age otherwise the value is lost? Why is it still working?

Thanks!

Comment: static mean created once and can be accessed with class name  so now you can think of age created once and hence value

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You've defined it as `static`, which means those are `class level` variables instead of instance level.

So when you call `$joe->haveBirthday();` it updates the `class level` variable of the `Person` class which can accessed using `Person::$age;`.

Static variables does not need to be returned, you can access it directly from Class.

Comment: This was helpful. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

`public static $age = 1;` suggests this is a static property, which means this as a class property, not an instance's.

Answer (score 0):

The method `haveBirthday()` does not return anything, it simply increase the static variable `$age`.

A static variable is shared by all instances of this classes. So it is not a good idea in your case, as all persons will have the same age.

```
class Person {
    public static $age = 1;

    public function haveBirthday() {
        static::$age +=1;
    }
}

$joe = new Person;
$jane = new Person;
$joe->haveBirthday();   // +1 => 2
$jane->haveBirthday();   // +1 => 3

echo Person::$age;  // Will return 3
```

Test it [here](https://eval.in/637074).